# How to disable TouchId authentication when I press logout - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to know how can I disable a function, in this case, `func enableTouchIDLogin(){}`. Everytime when a user logs out of the app, the touchid function is in my viewWillAppear function, which will automatically trigger the TouchID, making it a bad user experience if the user puts their finger on the home button, which will just log them into the app again.

Question is: What are some ways to disable TouchId or the function to be called right after the user presses the log out button? But to be called again as normal in viewWillAppear when the user comes back into the app from the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Store the login status (e.g. as a Boolean) in NSUserDefaults or maybe the Keychain (these are the most popular methods for persistent storage of this kind of data).
Then, in your case in your viewWillAppear function you'd check if the user is logged in (fetch that info from NSUserDefaults or then Keychain) and if yes, you ask for the fingerprint.